# storing matrices computed out of two for loops (appending a list did not work)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

i am implementing the Jacobi iterative method

The problem is i can not store the calculated matrix after each iteration, i tried to append into an empty list but it keeps overwriting the previous elements in that list and i end up with a single matrix repeated K times.

I need to subtract and operate on those matrices for convergence criteria

```
# Iterate Jacobi until convergence  
U = np.array([[8.9,8.9,8.9,8.9,8.9],[8.4,0,0,0,9.2],[7.2,0,0,0,9.4],[6.1,6.8,7.7,8.7,6.1]])
UI=U
UF=U
UFK=[]
k=0
while k<3:
    k=k+1 # update the iteration counter
    for i in range (1,Nx-1):
        for j in range (1,Ny-1):
            UF[j,i] = (UI[j+1,i]+UI[j,i+1]+UI[j-1,i]+UI[j,i-1])*0.25 #the matrix i want to store after each iteration 
    UFK.append(UF) # 
    print (UF) # when i print UF i get the correct matrix at each iteration displayed 

[[ 8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9       ]
 [ 8.4         4.325       3.30625     5.3515625   9.2       ]
 [ 7.2         4.58125     3.896875    6.83710938  9.4       ]
 [ 6.1         6.8         7.7         8.7         6.1       ]]
[[ 8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9       ]
 [ 8.4         6.296875    6.11132812  7.76210937  9.2       ]
 [ 7.2         6.0484375   6.67421875  8.13408203  9.4       ]
 [ 6.1         6.8         7.7         8.7         6.1       ]]
[[ 8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9         8.9       ]
 [ 8.4         7.36494141  7.67531738  8.47734985  9.2       ]
 [ 7.2         7.00979004  7.62979736  8.5517868   9.4       ]
 [ 6.1         6.8         7.7         8.7         6.1       ]]

print(UFK) # when i display the appended UFK it is just repeating a single matrix 3 times

[array([[ 8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ],
        [ 8.4       ,  7.36494141,  7.67531738,  8.47734985,  9.2       ],
        [ 7.2       ,  7.00979004,  7.62979736,  8.5517868 ,  9.4       ],
        [ 6.1       ,  6.8       ,  7.7       ,  8.7       ,  6.1       ]]),
 array([[ 8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ],
        [ 8.4       ,  7.36494141,  7.67531738,  8.47734985,  9.2       ],
        [ 7.2       ,  7.00979004,  7.62979736,  8.5517868 ,  9.4       ],
        [ 6.1       ,  6.8       ,  7.7       ,  8.7       ,  6.1       ]]),
 array([[ 8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ,  8.9       ],
        [ 8.4       ,  7.36494141,  7.67531738,  8.47734985,  9.2       ],
        [ 7.2       ,  7.00979004,  7.62979736,  8.5517868 ,  9.4       ],
        [ 6.1       ,  6.8       ,  7.7       ,  8.7       ,  6.1       ]])]
```

Comment: Please add the code, input and output directly - no screenshots.

Comment: You are right i edited my request. This is the first time i ask a question on stackoverflow i did not know how to add the code now i do :)

Comment: Thanks! Here are some more hints: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UI=U  # why?  UI is not a copy of U, it IS U
# UF=U  # another why?  Changes of UF will change UI and U as well
UFK=[]    # appending to a list is great
k=0
while k<3:
    k=k+1 # update the iteration counter
    UF = np.zeros_like(U)  # a fresh copy for iteration
    for i in range (1,Nx-1):
        for j in range (1,Ny-1):
            UF[j,i] = (UI[j+1,i]+UI[j,i+1]+UI[j-1,i]+UI[j,i-1])*0.25 
    UFK.append(UF) # 
    print (UF) 
print(UFK)
```

`UFK` should now be a list of the `k` `UF` arrays.

Since you are overwriting all elements of `UF` it doesn't matter how it it is initialed, just so long as it does not step on other arrays, including `UF` from previous iterations.

But on further thought, maybe changing `UI` is part of the plan.  If so, why obscure the fact with the `UF` and `UI` variables?  In this case you can collect the intermediate iterations with a `U.copy()` - that is, save a copy of `U` to the list, rather than the `U` itself.

```
for i... :
   for j....:
        U[j,i] = (U[j+1,i]+U[j,i+1]+U[j-1,i]+U[j,i-1])*0.25 
UFK.append(U.copy())
print (U)
```

A list contains pointers to objects.  If I write

```
alist = [U, U, U]
U[0,0] = 10000
```

that `10000` will appear in all 3 elements of the list - because they are the same thing.

In your code you case `UF` to the list, and then modify it at each iteration.  The result is that your list just contains `k` pointers to the same array.

Comment: Thank you it works with `UFK.append(U.copy())` !! You are absolutely right I am making my first steps in programming with python i did not know that `UI=U` and `UF=U` will overwrite the original, i wanted `U` to stay untouched. How do i keep it stored untouched in a variable? U is part of the plan since i am only modifying the interior of the matrix the first rows,columns will remain the same so `UF = np.zeros_like(U) ` wont help. Thanks again, you people rock i have too many things to learn.

Comment: I followed the same technique `UI=U.copy()` and now `U` is unchanged. Coool!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the dimension of UFK before you append it or you always replicate the same matrix several times. The following code can generate the output correctly:

```
UFK = np.array([]).reshape(0,5)
k = 0
while k < 3:
    k += 1
    for i in range(1, Nx-1):
        for j in range(1, Ny-1):
            UF[j, i] = (UI[j+1, i] + UI[j, i+1] + UI[j-1, i] + UI[j, i-1]) * 0.25
    UFK = np.append(UFK, UF, axis=0)
```

Another way to append the array is `UFK = np.vstack((UFK, UF))` which will give you the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much it is not exactly what i wanted but it is 80%, i had a list full of the matrices rows but they are separated i added a split and it works know:
    `while k<5:
    k=k+1 # update the iteration counter
    for i in range (1,Nx-1):
        for j in range (1,Ny-1):
            UF[j,i] = (UI[j+1,i]+UI[j,i+1]+UI[j-1,i]+UI[j,i-1])*0.25 #the matrix i want to store after each iteration 
    UFK = np.append(UFK, UF, axis=0)
#     UFK = np.vstack((UFK, UF)) 
    UI=UF
    print (UF) # when i print UF i get the correct matrix at each iteration displayed 
G=np.split(UFK,k)`

Comment: Appending to a list `UFK` is perfectly fine; in fact some of us argue that it is better than concatenating (`np.append`) to an array.